# NavController currentDestination is null?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I am using NavController to manages app navigation:

```
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

I got a few crashes in Crashlytics: I found it is because:

```
MyFragment {
     ...
    myLiveData.observer(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer) {
    
        findNavController().navigate(myAction) // currentDestination is null ...
     })
     ...
```

navController.currentDestination? is an optional, When it is null, app crashes with unhandled exception.

Since currentDestination is declared as optional, I guess there must be some legit reason why it could be null, that I don't know. Appreciate in advance for any pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue.
At seemingly random times, the navigate to my destination fragment would crash due to the currentDestination being null.
Similar to the OP, I was triggering the nav through a Flow (not a live data).
Despite collecting the flow with the viewLifecycleOwner, it almost seemed like the fragment wasn't ready to navigate.  What I found that fixed the issue was a little surprising.  It was how the previous fragment was "popping" itself.

```
FragA -> FragB
FragB.popBackStack()
FragA -> VERY Quickly re-nav to FragB (null currentDestination == Crash)
```

However, as a test, I tried using

```
FragB.popBackStack(fragA.id, false)
```

And the crashes stopped.  The currentDestination was never null again.
This must be a bug in the navComponent library.

My fix was as follows, and is still working (fingers crossed).
Instead of "findNavController.popBackStack()" I use

```
findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.let {
    findNavController().popBackStack(it.destination.id, false)
} ?: run {
    findNavController().popBackStack()
}
```

Hope that works for someone else also.

*edit* Left in for posterity.. but.. I was wrong. this didn't fix it afterall.  My mistake. Carry on.

Answer (score 0):

Destination represents the node in the [NavGraph](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavGraph) that's being hosted by the `NavHost`. `NavController` just manages the flow. There are few ocasions when `NavHost` is not showing any destination e.g.:

- before you set the `NavGraph` (because destination represents position in the graph)
- when you manually inflate something in the `NavHost` using transaction (outside of the graph's scope)

If you have multiple graphs in one app (e.g. [nested graphs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs), but can also be independent) you may have one `NavController` giving main graph destination and a secondary one returning null, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Stachu, any relationship to fragment viewLifecycle?

In my case, the navigation is triggered from a liveData observer, i.e.,

```
MyFragment {
 ...
myLiveData.observer(viewLifecyucleOwner, Observer) {

    findNavController().navigate(myAction) // currentDestination is null ...
 }
 ...
```